# Identifying Source of Coolant Leak on 1996 Chevy G10 Van

Tags: chevrolet, coolant-leak, g10-van

I have a 96 Chevy G10/Express 1500 van with 5.0 engine. In an effort to attempt diagnosing some driveability problems, I removed the dog house/engine cover. Quite quickly, I noticed a puddle/build-up of coolant around the left (facing the engine from the interior) intake manifold area. My initial impression was that the leak is from the intake manifold gaskets. I had the gaskets replaced recently, and, if I am honest, I am concerned about the quality of work provided by the gentlemen. The van is using more coolant than it should be, but not necessarily at an alarming rate.
[image]

[image]

I have a couple of questions:

- What is the most likely culprit for the leak pictured?
- If it is, as I, suspect a leaky intake manifold gasket, could this also cause driveabilty problems (by creating a vacuum leak)?

Comment: You're probably right about the intake gasket and it could cause a vacuum leak. Have you tried loosening and re-torquing the manifold bolts?

Comment: @Ben, No I have not. Thanks for the suggestion. Might have to talk to the gentleman who put it on in the first place. I don't think my torque wrench would work for the job (plus I am not sure about accessibility).

Comment: Are you aware of the “free” tool loaner program at your local Autozone parts store ?  One of the really nice tool sets in their system is a really nice coolant leak detector. You hook up a hand pump to the system, pressurize to 13 psi than look for leaks, safe, with the engine off.  You pay a deposit which is 100% refundable when you return the tool. Great way to verify the exact leak location.